# find in node js, if the zip file contains any .js or .exe or .json format, i want to block those type of upload

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I want to validate if the zip file contains any "js", "exe", "JSON" file

Whenever there is this type of file i want to handle it and not upload the same file to the s3 bucket.

```
const unzip = require('unzip'),
    fs    = require('fs'),
    inputFileName = '/home/nn/Downloads/delete.zip'; // zip file path 

fs.createReadStream(inputFileName)
    .pipe(unzip.Parse())
    .on('entry', (entry) => {
            console.log(entry);
            // how should i validate here
        }
        entry.autodrain();
    });
```

Comment: How do you define a "js" file? Is `script.js` one? Is `script.txt` which contains entirely JS code one? Is `readme.txt` which contains some JS snippets one?

Comment: I want to block using the extension, if a txt file contains a js code, i am not going to handle that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the path module, and use the extname(), which gives you the extension and then check from your vulnerable extensions using the includes

```
    const unzip = require('unzip'),
    fs    = require('fs'),
    path = require('path'),
    inputFileName = '/home/nayan/Downloads/delete.zip'; // zip file path 

fs.createReadStream(inputFileName)
    .pipe(unzip.Parse())
    .on('entry', (entry) => {
        const rest_file_path = ['.js', '.exe', '.zip'],
            extension = path.extname(entry.path);
        if (rest_file_path.includes(extension)) {
            console.log(`Cant upload this zip file as it contains ${extension} file`) // you can handle it here and send a error  response
        }
        entry.autodrain();
    });
```